# Ruby on Rails: db:schema:load fails due foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

okay,

I've been trying to wrap my head around this problem for a while, and I simply cannot come up with an explanation why this behavior is happening.
I have a project that's running Ruby 2.7, Ruby on Rails 5.2.8.1.

On a new system, I'm trying to set up the database using a MySQL 5.7 database, and every time I run `bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load` it fails because of a Foreign Key error. And the weird part is that it tries to create the Foreign Key before the actual tables, which is what doesn't make any sense to me as the `add_foreign_key` statement is the last statement in the `schema.rb`.

### Simplified schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20211230212616) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci" do |t|
    t.integer "category_id", null: false
    t.string "subtitle"
    t.text "page_content"
    t.text "pinned_styles"
    t.text "unpinned_styles"
    t.text "updated_by"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_categories_on_category_id", unique: true
  end

  create_table "faqs", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci" do |t|
    t.text "question"
    t.text "answer"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_faqs_on_category_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "faqs", "categories"
end
```

### Error Message

```
bundle exec db:drop db:create db:schema:load

-- create_table("categories", {:force=>:cascade, :options=>"ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci"})
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories` CASCADE
/Users/olivar/RubymineProjects/catalog/db/schema.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
/Users/olivar/RubymineProjects/catalog/db/schema.rb:13:in `<main>'
/Users/olivar/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/Users/olivar/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'

Caused by:
Mysql2::Error: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
/Users/olivar/RubymineProjects/catalog/db/schema.rb:15:in `block in <main>'
/Users/olivar/RubymineProjects/catalog/db/schema.rb:13:in `<main>'
/Users/olivar/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/Users/olivar/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
```

Yet, every time the command fails because it creates the categories table, then it tries the foreign key, without the faqs table existing (or switches the tables).

**Can someone explain this behavior?**

Comment: The database is empty. I’ll update the “id” column in the example to reflect a different value, that ain’t the Problem. The entire schema works when I remove the foreign key statement but then I don’t have the FK in the database

Comment: can you post the error that you're getting, to make sure we're on the same page here, maybe I'm getting something different.

Comment: Please don't try to use the `schema.rb` dump I've posted, this is a cleaned up, simplified version to illustrate the problem I am describing, the complete one has around 12 more tables. The core problem is that it tries to run the `add_foreign_key` statement prior to creating both tables it's supposed to reference, and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: I've added the error message, where it shows it creates the table `categories` and then tries to do the foreign key instead of creating the table `faqs` first.

Comment: if `foreign_key` run first you'd see `-- add_foreign_key("faqs", "categories"...` first. you're getting an error from `create_table("categories"...`, if *categories* table exists (and it shouldn't!) it tries to drop it first `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'categories' CASCADE`, see that *CASCADE*, it's from create_table `force: :cascade`. it would only cause an issue if *categories* and *faqs* tables are present and there is fk constraint in *faqs*. because in mysql you're suppose to drop *faqs*  first, apparently. so either database is not dropping or there is something else, which I can't reproduce.

Comment: huh, interesting observation. I'm going to try some stuff on Monday and I'll update the topic with some findings. You've given me some things to investigate Alex ;)

Comment: I am running into this same issue. However when I seem to drop the database first using `rails db:drop` and then `rails db:create` followed by `rails db:schema:load` it seems to work. I am not sure why this is though. I can't understand the need to drop the database. re-create and then load the schema. Interested to hear if the same thing works for you? Maybe try running them in one go `bin/rails db:drop db:create db:schema:load`?...

Comment: yeah that works, but indeed, you need to drop everything...